# Ошибка 404 при попытке регистрации пользователя

Tags: android, c#, asp.net-mvc, retrofit, rxjava

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь организовать регистрацию пользователя из android приложения на сервере через API на ASP.NET.
Отправка данных формы производится через POST. Код JAVA:

```
@POST("/app/accounts/register")
Observable<Integer> userRegistration(@Body UserAPI body);
```

Класс UserAPI:

```
public class UserAPI {
   @SerializedName("id")
   @Expose
   private int id;
   @SerializedName("sid")
   @Expose
   private int sid;
   @SerializedName("full_name")
   @Expose
   private String full_name;
   @SerializedName("iin")
   @Expose
   private String iin;  
...}
```

Реализация функции userRegistration:

```
@Override
public Observable<Integer> userRegistration(UserAPI body) {
    return apiInterface.userRegistration(body)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

В контроллере сервиса (ASP.NET, C#):

```
// /app/accounts/register
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Register")]
    public int Register(User user)
    {
        return mModel.registerUser(user);
    }
```

Класс User в сервисе:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int sid { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string iin { get; set; }
}
```

При отправке из приложения android ошибок не возникает, однако сервис ни как не реагирует, а в ответ приходит 404 ошибка. 
В чем моя ошибка.

Comment: Разрешение на интернет в манифесте есть?

Comment: Все разрешения есть. Более того, get запросы проходят и отрабатываются. Проблема только с POST.

Comment: Ну... Возможно у вас неправльно как-то URL в итоге формируется. Может первый слэш лишний (или последний ещё нужен). Может у вас в адресе где-то пробел появляется и он не преобразуется автоматом в  `%20` и, в итоге, просто игнорируется и получается неверный запрос.

Comment: а в метод `public int Register(User user)` на сервере заходит? а так же проверьте роуты для этого action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно проанализировав код приложения и сервера на предмет соответствия и правильности формирования адресов по совету ЮрийСП, выявил и устранил не корректный адрес. 
Однако, для полного решения проблемы потребовалось внести изменения в код контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Register")]
    public int Register([FromBody] User user)
    {
        return mModel.registerUser(user);
    }
```

А именно - добавить аннотацию [FromBody].
Всем спасибо за внимание.